# Idempotents in Laurent series

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, laurent-series, formal-power-series

I think it’s true that if $R$ is any commutative, unital ring, then if the formal Laurent series ring $R((t))$ is isomorphic to a Cartesian product of two rings $R((t)) \cong S_1 \times S_2$, then both factors are themselves Laurent series rings. That is, there must be rings $R_1$ and $R_2$ such that $S_i \cong R_i((t))$.

I can easily show this for the formal power series ring $R[[t]]$ using idempotents: equivalent to the existence of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are a complementary pair of idempotents $e+f=1$. If they are both contained in $R[[t]]$, then their degree-$0$ coefficients $e_0$ and $f_0$ are also idempotent. In particular $e_0 + f_0 = 1$, so $R[[t]] = (e_0R)[[t]] \times (f_0R)[[t]]$.

However, the existence of negative-degree coefficients is really complicating my attempts to prove the claim for $R((t))$ in the same way.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to continue, or know any alternative proofs, or a counterexample? Geometrically it seems like it should be true—I don’t see why $\mathrm{Spec}(R((t)))$ should be allowed to have more disjoint components than $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, but I’m really stuck here.

Comment: Also @KReiser, I thought your answer was valuable, even if it was incomplete—I hadn’t considered the relationship between idempotents of $A$ and $A/\sqrt{0}$ before, and your steps were well explained

Comment: @jackson unfortunately I'm a little busy as of late and I needed more time than I have to dig in to what was wrong, and I didn't want to leave an incorrect/incomplete solution out there. I'll see if I can't fix it soon, but I'm sure you understand that things can get busy.

Comment: @math54321 I think this may be a valid counterexample, and showed me an error in my “algebraic” proofs that the minimal degree can’t be $-1$ or $-2$. Can you write it up as an answer, and include a proof that $c_0 \neq 0$?

Comment: @math54321, My original reasoning was mistaken, as I realize now (it has some unacceptable cancellation). However, what you've shared should be a valid counterexample, if $c_0 \ne 0$. Any idempotent with minimal degree $<0$ implies that $R((t))$ has more idempotents than $R$ does, so some component $R_i((t))$ produces a counterexample

Comment: Since idempotents in $R$ are idempotent in $R((t))$ as well, the set of idempotents of $R((t))$ is generally a superset; by "more" I simply mean proper superset. There are some details I have not explained, but what I am most interested in is equivalent to the question of existence of such a counterexample